# iOS Video not working (streaming) Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, video, streaming, media

I cannot figure out why my video will not play on iOS device. Please let me know what I am missing. Also, yes, I imported the MediaPlayer.framework into the .h page. I created a button and called the action to play the video from a website upon click.

```
-(IBAction)playMovie:(id)sender{  
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.videopage/video"]:  

moviePlayer =  [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]  
                initWithContentURL:url];  

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self  
                                           selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:)  
                                           name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification  
                                           object:moviePlayer];  

NSString *version = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];  
BOOL isAtLeast84 = [version floatValue] >= 8.35;  
if (isAtLeast84) {  
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self  
                                             selector:@selector(moviePlaybackStateChanged:)  
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification  
                                               object:moviePlayer];  
}  

moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;  
moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;  
    [self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];  
[moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];  }

-(void) moviePlayBackDidFinish:(NSNotification*)notification  {  
MPMoviePlayerController *player = [notification object];  
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]  
 removeObserver:self  
 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification  
 object:player];  

if ([player  
     respondsToSelector:@selector(setFullscreen:animated:)])  
{  
    [player.view removeFromSuperview];  
}  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to check if the streaming is in one of the supported format:

> iOS supports many industry-standard video formats and compression
>   standards, including the following:
>
> • H.264 video, up to 1.5 Mbps, 640 by 480 pixels, 30 frames per second,
>   Low-Complexity version of the H.264 Baseline Profile with AAC-LC audio
>   up to 160 Kbps, 48 kHz, stereo audio in .m4v, .mp4, and .mov file
>   formats
> • H.264 video, up to 768 Kbps, 320 by 240 pixels, 30 frames per
>   second, Baseline Profile up to Level 1.3 with AAC-LC audio up to 160
>   Kbps, 48 kHz, stereo audio in .m4v, .mp4, and .mov file formats
> • MPEG-4
>   video, up to 2.5 Mbps, 640 by 480 pixels, 30 frames per second, Simple
>   Profile with AAC-LC audio up to 160 Kbps, 48 kHz, stereo audio in
>   .m4v, .mp4, and .mov file formats
> • Numerous audio formats, including
>   the ones listed in Audio Technologies

I tried your code with a basic project with only one button to start the video and it's working.